# Async Wait Efficient Execution

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I need to iterate 100's of ids in parallel and collect the result in list. I am trying to do it in following way

```
val context = newFixedThreadPoolContext(5, "custom pool")
val list = mutableListOf<String>()
ids.map { 
  val result:Deferred<String> =  async(context) {
    getResult(it)
  }
//list.add(result.await()
}.mapNotNull(result -> list.add(result.await())
```

I am getting error at

```
mapNotNull(result -> list.add(result.await())
```

as await method is not available. Why await is not applicable at this place? Instead commented line
`//list.add(result.await()` 
is working fine.

What is the best way to run this block in parallel using coroutine with custom thread pool?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you go in the right direction: you need to create a list of `Deferred` and then `await()` on them.

If this is exactly the code you are using then you did not return anything from your first `map { }` block, so you don't get a `List<Deferred>` as you expect, but `List<Unit>` (list of nothing). Just remove `val result:Deferred<String> =` - this way you won't assign result to a variable, but return it from the lambda. Also, there are two syntactic errors in the last line: you used `()` instead of `{}` and there is a missing closing parenthesis.

After these changes I believe your code will work, but still, it is pretty weird. You seem to mix two distinct approaches to transform a collection into another. One is using higher-order functions like `map()` and another is using a loop and adding to a list. You use both of them at the same time. I think the following code should do exactly what you need (thanks @Joffrey for improving it):

```
val list = ids.map { 
    async(context) {
        getResult(it)
    }
}.awaitAll().filterNotNull()
```

Comment: Your answer is actually better explained. I'm removing mine.

Comment: Haha, actually it made me laugh, how similar these two answers were :-D They were twin answers, I'm disappointed you removed yours ;-) @Joffrey

Comment: Yeah that was funny, and the timing as well :D But since the content was so similar I guess it makes more sense to keep just one answer, and your explanations are more detailed here

Comment: Also it might be worth noting that `awaitAll()` would be more appropriate because it fails earlier than `map { it.await() }`. It would require to filter the nulls afterwards though.

Comment: Sounds like a nice improvement, I updated my answer.